# how to split delimiter with numbers

Tags: jquery, openai-api

I am using openai to get subject lines, choices returning string not array/object, i need to split string by numbers.

```
var choices = "1. "Don't Miss Out: Exclusive Deals Inside!" 2. "Hurry! Limited Time Offer Inside" 3. "Unlock Savings: Open This Email Now" 4. "Last Chance to Save Big"";
choices = choices.split('/[0-9]+\./');
console.log(choices)
```

this is not working for me. its showing all string into single array index.

i needed output as

```
["Don't Miss Out: Exclusive Deals Inside!","Hurry! Limited Time Offer Inside","Unlock Savings: Open This Email Now","Last Chance to Save Big"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the RegExp without quotes:

```js
const choices = `1. "Don't Miss Out: Exclusive Deals Inside!" 2. "Hurry! Limited Time Offer Inside" 3. "Unlock Savings: Open This Email Now" 4. "Last Chance to Save Big"`;
const choicesArr = choices.split(/\d+\./);
console.log(choicesArr);
```

Edit: Changed RegExp to use \d according to Roko suggestion.

Comment: Use simply `\d+` for *any integer*. The syntax *[<int>-<int>]* is used in cases such as specific integer *ranges* like `[6-8]`. When you need `[0-9]` it's easier to write `\d`

Answer (score 0):

Open AI is perfectly capable of returning the output in the format you want. Instead of parsing the returned output instruct the AI to return the output to you in as a JSON array of strings.

Comment: What if the OP doesn't know how to do that? Be a better answer if you showed how.

Answer (score 0):

While there is the option of `choices.split(/[0-9]+\./)` you could always do:

```js
const choices = `1. "Don't Miss Out: Exclusive Deals Inside!" 2. "Hurry! Limited Time Offer Inside" 3. "Unlock Savings: Open This Email Now" 4. "Last Chance to Save Big"`

const res = choices.split(new RegExp('\d+\.', 'g'));
console.log(res)
```

Also, note your string is invalid. You would have better luck using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).